# coinmarketcap api v2 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, bitcoin

Coinmarketcap is updating their API to version 2. Can you help me access the JSON array structure as it is different than API version 1? The array path is data, #-of-crypto-token, quotes, USD, price. I would like to produce different functions to display the different token prices.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/", 
   function(data, status) {
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
       if (data[i].name == "bitcoin") {
          $("#bitcoin").html(data[i].price);
       }
     }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: layout of code so it is easier to see what it is doing

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to iterate through response and this is what I finally got:

```js
    $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/", function(data, status){
        for(var key in data.data){
            var coin = data.data[key];
            console.log("coin: ",coin.name,"--price: ", coin.quotes.USD.price)
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Just change my `console.log` to whatever you need and there you go.

PS: The demo code snippet here does not show all the coins, it rather cuts a number of them from beginning and shows the rest. It won't cause a problem for you though, no worries.